# What are the advantages and disadvantages of flattening json or not?

Tags: json, performance, flatten

I am currently working on json api designing for my project. I have searched on internet and find that there are nearly two styles of json. One is like

```
{
    "user":{
        "id":12,
        "name":"Jack",
        "address":{
            "city":"New York",
            "post":"123456"
        }
    }
}
```

And the other is like:

```
{
    "user.id":12,
    "user.name":"Jack",
    "user.address.city":"New York",
    "user.address.post":"123456"
}
```

I think the first one is OK, but since the second one appears, there must be some reason. So I want to know **the differences especially the performance differences** between the two formats. And I've searched on google, stackoverflow and some other websites to find an answer. But I haven't got one that is particular. Of course, [Why and when do we need to flatten JSON objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833379/why-and-when-do-we-need-to-flatten-json-objects) shows some useful information, but still no performance comparison.
  I'd appreciate it if any one have good answers.

Comment: One obvious point is space use, especially in decent size json objects with deep trees.

Comment: You mean a flattened json object needs more space because of the redundant uses of "father keys"?

Comment: Yeah (though you probably knew that already)

Comment: Thank you. And what about the performance differences between converting a java object to the normal json format and to the flattened format?

Comment: Flatter version will probably usually be not faster (because of size), but whether it will make any practical/noticeable difference depends on what this json is.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's basically a tradeoff between compactness, read performance, and write performance. For example, see this synthetic benchmark on a flat vs nested object 6 nodes deep where access is 33x faster on the flat object: https://jsbench.me/i3laj4m2ch/1. I don't have stats on an "average" increase in size between flat vs nested, but it's going to be considerable on an object of any complexity. Likewise, writes are going to be a LOT slower on a flattened object when modify values at the top of the object tree, since a great many paths will need to be accessed and updated.

You can basically think of the flattened object as a type of key value index on the nested object. And like adding any index to a database, it's going to give you better read performance but at the cost of memory and write performance.