# C# Initialize class and assign values Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json.net

Based on this code in this discussion ([How to build object hierarchy for serialization with json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978904/how-to-build-object-hierarchy-for-serialization-with-json-net)),  how would I initialize the JNotification and assign values to to JNotification which contains JPayload, JCustomData, JFilter?

```
public class JNotification
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public JPayload payload = new JPayload();
    public JFilter filter = new JFilter();
}

public class JPayload
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public JCustomData customData = new JCustomData();
}

public class JCustomData
{
    public string addType { get; set; }
    public string addTitle { get; set; }
    public string addMessage { get; set; }
    public int addAppraiserId { get; set; }
    public int addAppraisalId { get; set; }
    public int addAppraisalCommentId { get; set; }
    public int addAppraisalStatusHistoryId { get; set; }
}

public class JFilter
{
    public int AppraiserId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the object graph, serialize to json and deserialize, do:

```
var data = new JNotification() {
    status = "New",
    payload = new JPayload() {
        title = "SomeTitle",
        message = "msg",
        customData = new JCustomData() { ... }
    },
    filter = new JFilter() {
        AppraiserId = 1
    }
}
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
JNotification dataAgain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JNotification>(json);
```

Above using the `Newtonsoft.Json` NuGet package.

Please note that if you want to use the default naming convention of C#, you can set the serializer up to lowercase the first letter of each property.

There are also attributes to configure the output (if you want to skip a property, use strings for enums, etc.)

Comment: Troels, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure json deserialization will call the no-arg public constructor. If you construct those objects in the constructor of the JNotification, they should be initialized.